# Prove that the edges of a connected undirected graph G....

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Prove that the edges of a connected undirected graph G can be directed to create a strongly connected graph if and only if there is no bridge in G.

Comment: This is known as [Robbins' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins'_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

If there is a bridge then strong orientation is not possible since vertices on one side of the bride will be unreachable to the otherside no matter what orientaion is given to the bridge.

If there is no bridge then a strong orientation is always possible using what the wikipedia article calls ear-decomposition. Since G has no bridge it must have a cycle. You can then give the cycle an orientation you choose . Then this cycle will be a strongly connected. If u is a vertex outside the cycle then since connected to a vertex v on the the cycle via a non-bridge that is a cycle. then you can orient all edges on this cycle till you reach a vertex on the  oriented cycle. Thus you have expanded the current strongly connected cycle. This is can be proved via a proof by contradiction where you first assume to pick the largest strongly connected component and then expand it to get a contradiction.